# Saved macro and userform to the wrong file by accident. How can I recover it?

Tags: vba, excel

Did some great work with some VBA and a `Userform`. 
Unfortunately my work was saved to the wrong project. It was in this stupid `FUNCRES.XLAM` (whatever that is.)

I reopened excel. FUNCRES is there but my work is gone!!!! Where did it go?

Comment: I saved the FUNCRES file I am pretty sure.

Comment: Open that file again and hit saveas, see where the directory is that it defaults to. See if there is another file there. That might be where you saved it.

Answer (score 0):

XLAM is an addin so you need to make sure it is active first

In office 2013 you can check via:
File -> Options ->Addins
at the bottom click "Go" you will then see a list of addins so check it if not already checked.

You should then be able to edit using alt+f11

Good luck